# sonarqube with both androidTest and test covarage

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

I'm trying to setup sonarqube reporting in my Android project. I currently have trouble with showing all test classes in the sonar UI, the coverage is shown in percentages and currently only the unit test from `app/src/test/` are shown as Unit Tests.

My project has a test folder `app/src/test/` which contains unit test and I have a androidTest folder `app/src/androidTest/` which contain android unit, integration and UI tests. When I run all the tests via gradle the android-gradle plugin generates `build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec` and `build/test-results/debug/TEST-*Test.xml` which contains the jacoco results and coverage report for the unit test in the test folder. Also the android-gradle plugin generates `build/outputs/code-coverage/connected/coverage.ec` and `build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/TEST-*Test.xml` contain the results and coverage reports from the androidTest folder

In my build.gradle I can specify the properties for the sonar plugin.

```
 sonarqube {
        properties {
            property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java,src/main/res"
            property "sonar.tests", "src/test/java,src/androidTest/java"

            property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
            property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "${project.buildDir}/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec"
            property 'sonar.jacoco.itReportPath', "${project.buildDir}/outputs/code-coverage/connected/coverage.ec"

            property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "${project.buildDir}/test-results/debug" // path to junit reports
        }
    }
```

With `sonar.junit.reportsPath` I can specify which xml report is sent to the sonarqube server. When I change it to `build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected` I get the androidTest shown as Unit Test on the dashboard. Is there a way to make the sonar plugin look in both directories or merge the results together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-4101 is fixed, the only option you have is to write a task that copies your test result files into a single place and configure that as `sonar.junit.reportsPath`, like this:

```
task combineTestResultsForSonarqube {
    group = "Reporting"
    def modules = ["app", "and", "other", "modules"];
    doLast {
        modules.each { module ->
            File combined = file("${module}/build/combined-test-results")
            if (combined.exists()) {
                combined.deleteDir()
            }
            combined.mkdirs();

            def testDirs = [file("${module}/build/test-results/debug/"),
                            file("${module}/build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/")];
            testDirs.each { testDir ->
                if (!testDir.exists()) {
                    logging.captureStandardOutput LogLevel.WARN
                    println "WARNING: ignoring non-existant ${testDir.path}"
                    return;
                }
                files(testDir.listFiles()).each { file ->
                    new File(combined, file.getName()) << file.text
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Paths of course have to be adapted when you have flavors in your build.

Comment: Though this may add the UI test in the SonarQube test list, it does not increase your coverage % or indicate that methods are covered. Any solution for this?

Comment: @Elias If you're using Jacoco for instrumentation and code coverage, you're set, because newer versions of Sonarqube merge Jacoco coverage data from unit and instrumentation tests. I'm however not aware that this is possible for other coverage plugins.

Comment: We are on SonarQube v6, which I suppose is the latest? I pass these properties:

property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "build/jacoco/testProductionMinSdk19DebugUnitTest.exec" // junit coverage report
        property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "build/test-results/productionMinSdk19Debug/" // path to junit reports
        property "sonar.android.lint.report", "/build/outputs/lint-results-productionMinSdk19Debug.xml" // path to lint report